# while loop inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays

i'm trying to create a hierarchical select menu with multiple selection.
i select the categories and i store them in an array comma separated.etc(1,5,10). everything works fine except that each time i select another value the while loop echo's duplicate values on drop down list.
Is there any other way i could do this without having duplicate values?

```
$tree = '<select name="an_det_category[]" class="an_det_category"  multiple>';
$var=explode(",",$row_detail_rec['an_det_category']); 
print_r(array_values($var))
foreach ($var as $var1){

    $result10 = mysql_query("select * from announcment_categories where an_parendid=0 and an_langid=".$_GET['langid']."");          
            while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result10)){     
                        if ($row['an_location']==$var1){$ka='"selected="selected"">'; 
                         }else{
                             $ka='">';
                             }

                        $tree .= '<option value="'.$row['an_location'].$ka;
                        $tree .= $row['an_name'];
                        $tree .= '</option>';
                        $tree .= getLowerRanks($row['an_location'],1,$var1);                                
        }       
}
$tree .= '</select>';
```

Comment: Try adding an array, store the variable in a new position on each loop, and check in the while loop for the `in_array` method. Then you can stop it from having duplicate results by 'skipping' the duplicates.

Comment: What is `getLowerRanks()`? I have an answer, but it gets rid of the `foreach` loop, so there's no `$var1`. I don't know what to do for that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do a `for` loop. Just loop through the database results, and use `in_array` to test whether the current category is in one of the selected categories.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result10)) {
    if (in_array($row['an_location'], $var)) {
        $ka = 'selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $ka = '';
    }
    $tree .= "<option value='{$row['an_location']}' $ka>";
    $tree .= $row['an_name'];
    $tree .= '</option>';
    // I'm not sure what this is, or how to reproduce it in this version
    // $tree .= getLowerRanks($row['an_location'], 1, $var1);
}
```

Comment: I guess `getLowerRanks` wasn't important?

Comment: getLowerRanks is a function for getting the subcategory of a category